# Is data storage type different between linked list and array?

Tags: arrays, linked-list

Recently I got a problem when sovling the next problem:

**What is the difference between a linked list and an array?**

A. Search complexity when both are sorted
B. Dynamically add/remove
C. Random access efficiency
D. Data storage type

I know A,B and C are correct, but I feel confused about D. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no difference between them from the perspective of datastorage type.(And maybe it should also be said from the perspective of a statically typed programming language) You can put any struct or any object into them. The key is in most programming languages they are one of types which means you can just store one type on them. However in linked list you store a pointer to the next element. So if you construct your own linked list in a programming language you can put any type into them as long as you keep the pointer to the next element. Whereas in arrays the elements are reached via pointer arithmetic. So they have to be one of type no matter what. So linked list are more flexible from the perceptive of the data storage type.

Comment: I think your answer is reasonalbe, so I accept it if there are no other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the author means array is stored contiguous in memory, while the linked list is not.